# Array of arrays and subroutines

Tags: arrays, perl, substr

I'm having a difficult time in perl with array of arrays and subroutines. I am trying the word ladder problem where I want to find a some sequence of steps between two words given some dictionary. When I attempt to run my perl program I get warnings at my string comparison step. Here is my simplified approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = ("this", "that", "thin", "thus", "past");
my $myword = "thip";
my $end = "thus";
my @aoa = ([$myword]);
my $diff_chars = 0;
my $i = 0;

foreach (@aoa){
  #push a word from @list with one letter difference onto our $_
  push $_, routine($_, $_->[-1]);
  push @aoa, $_;
  #if we the last element in our list matches the end then we are done
  if($_->[-1] eq $end){
    print "we found a path via $_\n";
    last;
  }
}

sub routine{
  my @arr = @{$_[0]};
  my $mines = $_[1];
  my $index = 0;
  foreach my $word (@list){
    $diff_chars = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $index++;
    next if grep{$_ eq $word} @arr;
    foreach my $char (split //, $word){
      if($char ne substr $mines, $i, 1){
        $diff_chars++;
      }
      $i++;
    }
    if($diff_chars == 1){
      #remove $word from list to remove possible duplicates
      splice @list, $index, 1;
      return $word;
    }
  }
}
```

Upon running this, I get an infinite loop that continues to output the warning

```
substr outside of string at t.pl line 33.
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at t.pl line 33.
```

which is my `if($char ne substr $mines, $i, 1)` line. I am unsure why I am getting this and have been trying to fix this error for a couple hours now and could really use some help.

Comment: Have you looked to see what `$mines` is at the time you get that warning? (Hint: it's probably the empty string `''`)

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to build this 'ladder'. Do you want an end result to be an array containing `('this', 'thin')`?

Comment: It is great that you post code, of course, but I'd suggest you add a precise worded description of the algorithm.